# rewrite rule for single or multiple folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My htaccess code for URL rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^compare/(.*)/?$ compare.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^compare/(.*)/(.*)?$ compare.php?page=$1&location=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This rule works for :

```
www.example.com/compare/car
```

But it is not working for:

```
www.example.com/compare/car/india
```

I want to modify the rewrite rule which works for these urls:

```
www.example.com/compare/car
www.example.com/compare/car/india
```

Is it possible? How can I modify my rewrite rule to achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application) instead of adding a bunch of different rules in your htaccess. It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. And since you only need one single rule (that redirects all requests to non-existing files to index.php), it's easier to move it between web servers (not all use htaccess).

Comment: Try changing `(.*)` to `([^/])` in both your checks and see if that works better. `(.*)` matches anything (including slashes) so the first rule matches both those URL's.

Comment: @M.Eriksson RewriteRule ^compare/([^/])?$ compare.php?page=$1&location=$2 [L,QSA] --- I tried this.. its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. `.*` in first rule is too greedy which matches a `/` so first rule is also matching `/compare/car/india` as well as `/compare/car`
2. Since your URI is starting with `/compare` and rule is rewriting to `compare.php` you need to turn off content negotiation by turning off `MultiViews`.
3. Your last rule is without any `RewriteCond` as that is only applicable to next immediate `RewriteRule` directive.

You may use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# one path element after compare
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]+)/?$ compare.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# two path elements after compare
RewriteRule ^compare/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ compare.php?page=$1&location=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```